# Output of SQL Server table contents in one line with trailing total contains unwanted XML tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of data in MS SQL Server whose contents I need to format in a single line, along with a trailer record containing the number of records. I am using T-SQL's for-xml-path command to create the string but the output contains XML tags that I need to remove.

The script follows:

```
create table #data (
    record_id int identity(10000,1) primary key,
    create_ts datetime not null default current_timestamp,
    transit varchar(20),
);

insert into #data (transit) values (12345);
insert into #data (transit) values (5432);

with records as (
    select
    (
        right('00000' + rtrim(transit), 5)
        + convert(varchar, create_ts, 12)
    ) as val
    from #data
    where datediff(hh, create_ts, getdate()) <= 24
)

select * from records
union all
select (
    + convert(varchar, GetDate(), 12)
    + right('00000000000' + convert(varchar, count(*)), 11)
)
from records
for xml path('');
```

I am seeing this output:

```
<val>12345140710</val><val>05432140710</val><val>14071000000000002</val>
```

but need the output to not include the XML tags:

```
123451407100543214071014071000000000002
```

What change do I have to make to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always I find my own answer after posting to StackOverflow. I solved this by copying the raw data (as opposed to formatted data) into the temporary table and formatted everything in the final select:

```
with records as (
    select *
    from #data
    where datediff(hh, create_ts, getdate()) <= 24
)

select (
    select
        right('00000' + rtrim(transit), 5)
        + convert(varchar, create_ts, 12)
    from records
    for xml path('')
), (
    convert(varchar, GetDate(), 12)
    + right('00000000000' + convert(varchar, count(*)), 11)
)
from records
for xml path('');
```

Output is now:

```
123451407100543214071014071000000000002
```

Answer (score 2):

The tags in the output are the result of the fact that the column produced by the query has a name. So, you could just make it a nameless column to eliminate the tags.

To do that, you could replace the `*` in your original query with something like `val + ''`:

```
with records as (
    select
    (
        right('00000' + rtrim(transit), 5)
        + convert(varchar, create_ts, 12)
    ) as val
    from #data
    where datediff(hh, create_ts, getdate()) <= 24
)

select val + '' from records
union all
select (
    + convert(varchar, GetDate(), 12)
    + right('00000000000' + convert(varchar, count(*)), 11)
)
from records
for xml path('');
```

And you would get the output you wanted:

```
123451407100543214071014071000000000002
```

Comment: Another way to create a "text only" node  is to use the wildcard `*` as a column alias. [Columns with a Name Specified as a Wildcard Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500154.aspx)